# How to use multiple output from Nsolve?

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value, output, transformation

I have 3 simultaneous equations and 3 unknowns. The values are coming to be right. But how do I assign these 3 values in the respective variables?

```
[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3}, {qn, qr, k}]
```

> ```
> {{qn -> 350.23, qr -> 175.115, k -> 242.926}}
> ```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? it is in general not a good idea. For example, once you assign value to say  `k` then it is no longer symbol. Now all your equations will automatically be updated once you try to use them later, and all the variables in them will change to numbers. If you try to use these equations later, they will not have the original symbolic structure. In general, It is better to keep solve results as is, i.e. as rule, and use replacements to assign values to equations or other expressions that have these symbols in them. This way your equations remain symbolic.

Comment: actually this is the last step of computation. now i will calculate all other variables based on these values. so please help me.

Comment: Check documentation for using replacement rules (which is what `NSolve` returns).

Comment: `{qn, qr, k} = {qn, qr, k} /. sol`

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time.  Assign the list to a variable.

```
sol = {{qn -> 350.23, qr -> 175.115, k -> 242.926}} // Flatten

qn = qn /. sol 
qr = qr /. sol
k = k /. sol
```